# How do I create a RSA key pair so that it can be stored in a database?

Tags: java, rsa

i'm trying to implement a mutating encryption algorithm (theoretically developed by me) and as part of the requirements i need to generate an RSA key pair and store it in the database so that it can be retrieved later as part of the encryption process(only used to encrypt a session key so that it can be sent securely with the encrypted message).

my attempt on generating an RSA key pair seem to work however it keeps generating the same values over and over again instead of giving new pairs everytime the code is ran. what did i do wrong?
also if those values are dependent on the machine itself (thus displaying the same values) is there a way to link the key pair generation to the email address provided so that every time a new email address is inputted a different RSA key pair will be outputted?

the following code is my attempt to generate the key pair:

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.*;
/**
 * @author Speedy gonzales
 */
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,        NoSuchProviderException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(1024);

        byte[] publicKey = keyGen.genKeyPair().getPublic().getEncoded();
        StringBuffer retString1 = new StringBuffer();
        retString1.append("[");

        for (int puk = 0; puk < publicKey.length; ++puk) {
            retString1.append(publicKey[puk]);
           // retString1.append(", ");
        }
        retString1 = retString1.delete(retString1.length()-2,retString1.length());
        retString1.append("]");
        System.out.println(retString1);

          byte[] privateKey = keyGen.genKeyPair().getPrivate().getEncoded();
        StringBuffer retString2 = new StringBuffer();
        retString2.append("[");

        for (int pri = 0; pri < privateKey.length; ++pri) {
            retString2.append(privateKey[pri]);
           // retString2.append(", ");
        }
        retString2 = retString2.delete(retString2.length()-2,retString2.length());
        retString2.append("]");
        System.out.println(retString2); 
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: All I know about writing encryption algorithms is that you should never attempt it unless you are a cryptographic mathematics genius.

Comment: @user1515834: That's not what he asked for.  Stick to the provided question.

Comment: I don't know much about this particular implementation, but my first port of call would be to check the rng seed, if you're getting the same results every run.

Comment: @Wug It's a valid point to make - it was the first thing that sprung to my mind when I read the question.

Comment: He's not asking how to write the algorithm, which is the general red flag I use.

Comment: I tried running your application and I do not get the same values each time. Remember that there will be many similar bytes in the output due to the formats typically used by `getEncoded()` (e.g. ASN.1 key objects in DER format).

Comment: @ Duncan:i just retested the code and it is changing. have no idea what was the issue with my machine. Just re-ran the code after a re-start.
thanks
@wug that idea is very good thanks.
from what i gathered from your answer the key pair i'm generating is not related therefore will not work on a rsa encryption am i correct?

Comment: It certainly seems that way.  Unless the KeyPairGenerator object you have will repeatedly produce the same keypair, which I'm led to believe it won't. Yeah, I checked the javadocs and it won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your first problem is:

```
keyGen.genKeyPair().getPublic().getEncoded();
keyGen.genKeyPair().getPrivate().getEncoded();
```

You're not saving the keypair, so you are generating public and private keys that don't match.  From the javadocs, `genKeyPair()` behaves as follows:

> This will generate a new key pair every time it is called.

Secondly, getEncoded() just returns the key as a byte array.  If your database can store binary values, just store it that way.  Otherwise, you would probably have much better luck converting it to a String somehow.  You could, for example, base 64 encode it with this neat little trick (probably more reliable that what you're doing):

```
String keyAsString = new BigInteger(publicKey.getEncoded()).toString(64);
```

You can subsequently get the original bytes back with:

```
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(keyAsString, 64).toByteArray();
```

You say that you're getting the same value every run (and make SURE you are before bothering with this), and I'm not 100% sure why.  You should be able to access the algorithm parameters (you might have to cast the key to a different type), try printing those to see if they are the same.  Someone mentioned checking your random number generator, that might be a good idea too.

Comment: See my comment in the original question - I believe the OP is getting *similar* outputs from the method and assuming they are identical. In fact, they simply look similar because the ASN.1 objects returned by `getEncoded()` have several necessarily dentical headers/fields.

Comment: Quite possible.  OP is probably afk or something, hasn't been active since asking question